# Android NDK c++ helloworld program crash

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

As a Android NDK starter, I try to run helloJni example that I found in ndk website here:
https://developer.android.com/ndk/samples/sample_hellojni.html

I managed to compile and run with program with the c code provided in the project. However, I want to convert the code into C++ equivalent. Hours have been spent with no success.

What I have done:

rename jni/hello-jni.c -> jni/hello-jni.cpp

change in jni/android.mk

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hello-jni.c
```

to

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hello-jni.cpp
```

replacing c code with following c++ code in jni/hello-jni.cpp

```
#include <string.h>
#include <jni.h>

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
  Java_com_example_hellojni_HelloJni_stringFromJNI
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)
  {
        return env->NewStringUTF("Hello from C++ over JNI!");
  }
```

Building is successful with output

```
/home/wenchao/Projects/shared/android-ndk-r10e/ndk-build all 
Android NDK: WARNING: APP_PLATFORM android-21 is larger than android:minSdkVersion 8 in ./AndroidManifest.xml    
[arm64-v8a] Install        : libhello-jni.so => libs/arm64-    v8a/libhello-jni.so
[x86_64] Install        : libhello-jni.so => libs/x86_64/libhello-jni.so
[mips64] Install        : libhello-jni.so => libs/mips64/libhello-jni.so
[armeabi-v7a] Install        : libhello-jni.so => libs/armeabi-v7a/libhello-jni.so
[armeabi] Install        : libhello-jni.so => libs/armeabi/libhello-jni.so
[x86] Install        : libhello-jni.so => libs/x86/libhello-jni.so
[mips] Install        : libhello-jni.so => libs/mips/libhello-jni.so

18:09:12 Build Finished (took 412ms)
```

But on my device , I got

```
Unfortunately, HelloJni is stopped.
```

And very strange, No output in Logcat. Logcat is completely blank. (this might be a separate issue I need to fix , though)

I do not know how to debug at all :(

Comment: C is not C++ is not C!

Comment: I know, but we can build c++ code with NDK right?

Comment: Who Is "we"? Hint: check my edit and think again.

Comment: What do you mean by your "edit"?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31503772/revisions

Comment: Oh, Thanks, That's a typo, I have made some edits overriding your edits. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: It was not me who it was not clear to. Just remember that C and C++ are **different** languages and ylu should not add C tags for C++ questions and vice versa.

Comment: Two things: First, try on a different device. Don't use an emulator, if you are using one. Second, change the minSdkVersion to 21, the actual target and try again

Comment: I am a bit confused, I never add a C tag to this question. Just to be clear, I want to write a C++ equivalent code of C .

Answer (score 3):

Got it.

We need the extern "C" wrap arround the c++ code

```
#include <string.h>
#include <jni.h>
extern "C" {


JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
  Java_com_example_hellojni_HelloJni_stringFromJNI
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)
  {
    return env->NewStringUTF("Hello from C++ over JNI!");
  }
}
```